# AWS Cloudformation dynamodb tablename has characters at the end

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a Dynamodb table though serverless SAM and this is what I have

```
  MyTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - AttributeName: Id
          AttributeType: S        
      KeySchema: 
        - AttributeName: Id
          KeyType: HASH   
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5             
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: KEYS_ONLY
```

The problem is that when the table is created it has a random set of characters at the end, so for example my table after being created in DynamoDB will look like this

**stackname-Stores-10H9IHDFESTE0**

Why are these random characters added at the end and how do I get rid of them?  Plus my code needs to read from this table and everytime I deploy something if these characters are added to the end, how do I solve this?  The same is true for the lambda function being deployed as well, it adds this weird characters at the end for eample my Lambda function once deployed looks like this

**stakcname-StoresFunction-1D1J4W48RVDUR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the name of the table and the name of the Lambda function in your SAM - under the `Properties` key in the respective resources:

`TableName: String`

`FunctionName : String`